# Percent signs in place of regular tags

Tags: html, css, ruby, haml

I stumbled on the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/vYBqQEd) and liked it a lot. I've never seen the HTML coded this way and I would like to understand what the author is doing here. There are no tags in the HTML pane but instead the author uses `%`. What does the `%` mean here and what is `$base-color`?

```
HTML
.container
  .column
    .til
      %h1 Taller de Diseño Gráfico II
      %p NARRATIVA VISUAL
    .sub
      %p TEMÁTICA
      %h3 Patrimonio Cultural Inmaterial
  .column.align-h
    .circle-wrapper
      - (1..5).each do |i|
        %a{:class => "circle #{i}"}(href="#")#{i}
  .column
    .contain.text1
      %h2 Evaluación 1
      %p Definición del problema o necesidad
      %p Metodología de la investigación
      %p Aproximación al problema
      %h4 20 de Agosto
    .contain.text2
      %h2 Evaluación 2
      %p Fundamentos y Marco teórico
      %p Búsqueda de información, recopilación de datos, estado del arte, otros
      %h4 24 de Septiembre
    .contain.text3
      %h2 Evaluación 3
      %p Definición de propuesta - Narrativa Visual
      %p Contenidos conceptuales
      %h4 15 de Octubre
    .contain.text4
      %h2 Evaluación 4
      %p Proceso: Construcción de propuesta audiovisual
      %h4 29 de Octubre
    .contain.text5
      %h2 Evaluación 5
      %p Entrega final y presentación
      %p Exposición en sala del proceso y audiovisual
      %h4 26 de Noviembre
```

Comment: To see what languages are used in a codepen, look at the headers of the HTML, CSS and JS panes. This one says it is Haml with SCSS and plain JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Haml code. In Haml, we write a tag by using the percent (`%`) sign and then the tag, for example: `%strong`, `%div`, `%body`, `%html`; any tag you want. Then, after the name of the tag is `=`, which tells Haml to evaluate Ruby code to the right and then print out the return value as the contents of the tag.

For example:

HTML:

```
<strong class="code" id="message">Hello, World!</strong>
```

Haml:

```
%strong{:class => "code", :id => "message"} Hello, World!
```

You can read more about Haml in the [tutorial](http://haml.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: @jaysonn: my pleasure :)